# How to influence the planner on Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-performance

I have the following:

1. a complex query, 'match', that returns about 200 rows (ids)
2. a huge table, 'usernames', indexed on id that maps them to usernames

When I try to left join the query (1) with the table (2) the planner decides to do a seq scan on the (2) table. This ends up taking about 90ms on my machine.

i.e:

```
   ->  CTE Scan on match l  (cost=0.00..3349.54 rows=167477 width=4) (actual time=3.458..5.188 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=1638.00..1638.00 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=66.537..66.537 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Buckets: 8192  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 2542kB
         ->  Seq Scan on usernames r  (cost=0.00..1638.00 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=0.019..27.595 rows=100000 loops=1)
 Planning time: 16.261 ms
 Execution time: 77.425 ms
```

If I add ('limit 200') in the query (1), the query time drops down to 15ms

```
   ->  CTE Scan on match l  (cost=0.00..4.00 rows=200 width=4) (actual time=3.623..6.163 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Index Scan using usernames_userid_idx on usernames r  (cost=0.29..6.71 rows=1 width=18) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=1 loops=200)
         Index Cond: (l.id = userid)
 Planning time: 4.682 ms
 Execution time: 10.093 ms
```

I understand that this is due to the planned not estimating correctly the number of returned rows of my 'match' query.

Is there anyway to hint the planner to do an Index Scan on the join, instead of the Seq Scan?

The complete query is:

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE 

WITH match AS

 (SELECT
   dist_match.match_userid AS id
     FROM

      (SELECT
        me.into_game AS into_game, r5.miles, r5.useridy AS match_userid
        FROM 
          (SELECT l.id AS userid,
           category,
           r2.game,
           r3.game AS into_game,
           distance AS into_distance
           FROM userids l 
           LEFT JOIN category r1 ON l.id = r1.userid
           LEFT JOIN games r2 ON l.id = r2.userid
           LEFT JOIN into_games r3 ON l.id = r3.userid
           LEFT JOIN into_distances r4 ON l.id = r4.userid 
           WHERE l.id = 68931) AS me
         LEFT JOIN user_distances r5 ON me.userid = r5.useridx
         WHERE r5.miles < me.into_distance) AS dist_match
       LEFT JOIN games r6 ON (r6.userid = dist_match.match_userid
       AND r6.game = dist_match.into_game) ***LIMIT 200***)

SELECT l.id,name FROM match l LEFT JOIN usernames r ON l.id = r.userid;
```

Comment: Please paste the query.

Comment: Note: If you're doing just inner joins, you can also do a `SELECT ... FROM userids l, category r1, games r2 ... WHERE l.id = r1.userid AND l.id = r2.userid AND ...`. Postgres will then be able to optimize order as he sees fit. See more here - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/explicit-joins.html

Comment: Well, that's what I thought too, but if I do as you say, it takes even longer. .5 sec..

Comment: The interesting part is that this works much faster in mysql with exact same data.. but I really prefer to use postgresql..

Comment: What if you rewrite the query without `WITH`? CTEs are optimization fences in PostgreSQL. http://blog.2ndquadrant.com/postgresql-ctes-are-optimization-fences/

Comment: I re-wrote the query with one explicit join and now works fine. Faster than mysql too. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can influence the planner with

```
set local enable_seqscan = off;
```

to see if it helps.

See more at http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-query.html

Comment: Kind of.. Now it creates a hash however before doing the index scan. I don't understand why, as I have an index in the that table. "   ->  CTE Scan on match l  (cost=0.00..3349.54 rows=167477 width=4) (actual time=3.373..6.087 rows=200 loops=1)
   ->  Hash  (cost=3245.29..3245.29 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=89.402..89.402 rows=100000 loops=1)
         Buckets: 8192  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 2542kB
         ->  Index Scan using usernames_userid_idx on usernames r  (cost=0.29..3245.29 rows=100000 width=18) (actual time=0.042..50.384 rows=100000 loops=1)"